# Spring application does not start outside of a package

Tags: java, spring

I am following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) tutorial to build a basic application with Spring. It is working flawlessly as long as I follow this sub-directory structure:

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── hello
```

If I move my `Application.java` and `ScheduledTasks.java` classes out of the hello package I get the following error:

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a `@ComponentScan` of the default package.
```

And a few seconds later, indeed...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@71fa8894: startup date [Wed Jan 18 22:19:12 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

My question is, why do I need to put my classes into a package? What use does it have? How can I avoid this error? Do I really need to use packages if it is a really simple application?

Comment: Check out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html. Your `@ComponentScan` is scanning every class in every jar in your entire classpath. This is bad.

Comment: For the same reason you don't keep all of your business papers in a giant pile on the floor of your office.

Comment: *"How can I avoid this error?"* Don't create classes in the *default* package.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Put your java files again to `hello` package.

When a class doesn’t include a package declaration it is considered to be in the *“default package”*. The use of the “default package” is generally discouraged, and should be avoided.

It can cause particular problems for Spring Boot applications that use `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotations, since ***every class from every jar***, will be read.

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html).

Answer (score 24):

I moved the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication from the default package to a specific package and it worked.

Comment: This issue occurs if you are miss 'package'  declaration in @SpringBootApplication annotated java class.So add 'package' in that java class if it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a blank Maven folder where Java folder was the last one. I added class MainApplication.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Further, I had to create a package within Java folder such as com.test and then I moved my MainApplication class into it. Note "package com.test;" Now this default package Spring boot is looking for.

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Then it worked fine.